Are there any good map builders for a 3d, non-planar map of unusual shape?
I'm currently in the start of worldbuilding for a TTRPG game set in a horror-sci-fi-fantasy pocket dimension that the characters fall through out of our standard world.

The map is non-planar (or globe shaped.)  The best way I can describe it is a sphere with a hyperboloid-shaped tube running through it, with the traversable areas existing in the filled area of the circle (not the hollowed-out hyperboloid section.) Ideally, I'd like to be able to label different points on the 3d model/map and write annotations, and also make the connecting lines between areas Honestly, I'm not even sure something with capabilities for this exists out there, and I might just be stuck working on paper to make anything that's legible to me ha-ha. Just figured I'd ask somewhere.

This looks like a torus. Use a rectangular map, but wrap the right-hand edge to the left, as we do with the Mercator projection, but also wrap the top to the bottom.

@RichardKirk that would be better posted as an answer

How familiar are you with the use of 3d software, such as Blender?

That map you have already looks professional enough

@Dragongeek not at all really but willing to learn. Mostly i'm worried about my small, crappy college student laptop holding up under the stress of it, especially since I don't really need a lot of the fine-tuned 3d modelling capabilities, and I don't know if blender has the annotation/notes features I'd want, to the point that it might be more efficient to just use pen and paper.

Consider freeCAD or TinkerCAD. I know freeCAD has everything you want. TinkerCAD may or may not, I'm not sure, as it is designed for novices, which basically means that most advanced functionality has been stripped out to reduce the UI complexity.

The shape you're talking about is called a toroid. We have some mapping options that might help you in our List of Worldbuilding Resources.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot++a+torus

I second working in Blender, because you have more options for customizing your work.  A map on an unusual 3d surface is likely to be a custom job.
It may take a bit of work to create something that truly fits your vision, but the Blender community is often eager to answer interesting questions.  Blender Stack exchange is a great option, but
you must have very specific technical questions.
I would suggest first drawing the map as a 2D object, an aerial view, and in your case, you could do it in an art program such as illustrator or inkscape. (.dxf, .svg are image file formats that Blender can import)

This then can be projected onto the more interesting geometric shape- your toroid or torus, in your case, it is like a donut. (knife project is the tool used in this example.)

It may be important to illustrate a cross-section, in which case, hiding half of your model may be necessary.
Blender gives you the opportunity to look at the object from multiple perspectives, options you might not have in traditional map making programs, and also render it as you like with fantasy elements.

Don't like it?  Change it.  Maybe you want a more horror (I thought of  the TV series "Stranger Things") vibe, so you could go with something more organic and bloody looking.
You can add glowing (emissive) lights or spheres to give it a more magical or interdimensional quality.
A proper map making program would be a timesaver, but if you want to try out some crazy ideas, Blender could also be fun.
Then in another image program you could add some labels. Photoshop, Affinity Photo, Gimp, Microsoft Paint.  Whatever image editor or interactive viewer that works.

Hope you have fun making something exactly as you want.

This is really cool! And I am now working on learning blender. Do you know if there's a function for adding notes attached to a certain object? or even to add a link in the editor to an outside note-taking application? For example, if I wanted to take notes about one of the sphere areas and wanted to have information linked to the location.

You can create text in Blender.  However, text is generally easier to add and edit in an external program with layers.  (Something like  Photoshop, Gimp, or Canva is probably going to be easier to go back to if you change your mind.)

Search 'How to add a clickable annotation in blender?' if you want an interactive model, this is really a different workflow then a 2D map.  It is possible to publish a model on Sketchfab with a limited number of annotations.

The mathematical world of Manifold Geometry is the underlying abstraction you are working with.  What you call a "map" sounds a lot like an atlas from manifolds.  An atlas is a collection of charts, each of which maps part of the shape into a Euclidean space (such as a 2d map).  As such, I'll give a shout out to common_goldfish's answer which includes practical examples of charts chosen to capture the key parts of your civilization.
The challenge you will have to grapple with is distortion.  There will be great distortion in this case because these shapes are very non-linear.  All map makers face this, and you will have to work with that.  common_goldfish's chart projects with quite a lot of distortion, but that's the price paid for capturing all of your civilization on one chart (similar to how Alaska and Greenland appear larger than they really are on a traditional Mercator projection map).
As for paths, you can avoid a lot of math if you put terrain in the way.  If the path one takes around the planet is based on the terran and whether it is passable, you don't always take the shortest path.  Finding the shortest path on a Riemann Manifold, called a geodesic, is not trivial mathematically.  We typically rely on calculus of variations to compute them.  But if you have mountain passes to traverse, you get to handwave all of that math.
